# '}' expected near '=' Program

Tags: lua

I am making a HTTP call.

```
local headers_value = { Content-Type = "multipart/form-data", 
                        Accept = "application/json", 
                        Authorization = "Basic ccccc==" }
```

The error I am getting is (Line 3 is the above code)

> Program starting as
>   '"C:\Users\idoladmin\Downloads\ZeroBraneStudio\bin\lua53_win64\lua53.exe"
>   -e "io.stdout:setvbuf('no')" "C:\Code\Lua\send_calltoCM.lua"'. Program 'lua53.exe' started in 'C:\Code\Lua' (pid: 3452).
>   C:\Users\idoladmin\Downloads\ZeroBraneStudio\bin\lua53_win64\lua53.exe:
>   C:\Code\Lua\send_calltoCM.lua:3: '}' expected near '=' Program
>   completed in 0.05 seconds (pid: 3452).

What am I missing?

Comment: `Content-Type` is not a valid identifier

Comment: you can keep teh name as `Content-Type` if you change the assignment to `['Content-Type']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can't use `Content-Type` directly in a table constructor because it's not an identifier.

You can use the `[]` syntax, like this:

```
local headers_value = { ['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data", 
                        Accept = "application/json", 
                        Authorization = "Basic ccccc==" }
```

The use of an identifier such as `Accept` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `['Accept']`, just as `headers_value.Accept` is syntactic sugar for `headers_value['Accept']`.